# PHP unlink error - path error

Tags: php, unlink

I am using same syntax as everyone else but... i can't get it to work.

I have tried quite a few options to unlink file from directory.

Summary:
delete.php (the file that executes the action) is in the main folder. 
The file (image) to be deleted is under the sub-directory "upload".

```
$file = $name . '.' . $ext; 

$tmpfile = 'upload/'. $file; 
unlink($tmpfile);
```

Than this one too.

```
if (!unlink("upload/$file")) {
    echo "Error deleting ... $file  ... from directory";
}
else {
    echo "Deleted $file";
}
```

And many more. 
Here is the error log

unlink(upload/Glauber_3232_MAGNOLIA_ST__016.jpg) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory in /home2/braaasil/public_html/openhouse/delete.php on line 30

Therefore, I am not being able to exit the main directory (where delete.php) is and go to subdirectory "upload" where my images are. 
Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

```
public_html

   openhouse (sub domain)

      delete.php (this is a file)

      upload (this is sub folder)
```

If this is not clear I can take a picture. delete.php and subfolder upload are on the same level, both kids of openhouse. Hope this is clear.

Comment: Are you sure that file /home2/braaasil/public_html/openhouse/upload/Glauber_3232_MAGNOLIA_ST__016.jpg exists? Note that file names are case sensitive.

Comment: Did you try `"../upload/$file"` ?

Comment: Not saying this is your problem, but you should always use relative paths based on the current directory: `__DIR__ . '/upload/' . $file`. Because sometimes the current working dir is not what you think it is.

Comment: I tried "../upload/$file"   The problem is that it is trying to find the file inside the delete.php per error message as ../delete.php/my_image_to_be_delete.jpeg

Answer (score 4):

Your script has no issues but I believe you're giving the wrong path to your application, so it is unable to find specified file under upload folder.

I think you're using a subfolder, but `upload` points to root folder, hence it can't find the folder.

Try: `unlink (__DIR__ . '/upload/' . $file);`

If it works, you can also use it as: `"./upload/$file"`

Comment: @PeeHaa; You probably edited my comment while I was editing it myself.

Comment: @Imaqtpie this is now wrong again - `__DIR__` doesn't have a trailing slash.

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton Sorry, it was accidently overwritten. I've added it.

Comment: I am new to PHP so pardon my ignorance. I used your script as it there. No change. Got this again.  "No such file or directory in /home2/braaasil/public_html/openhouse/delete.php" for some reason  i can't get this: home2/braaasil/public_html/openhouse/upload/ (then the  image to be delete)"

Comment: Yes, it is a subfolder. delete.php is in the main folder. Images are in the sulfolder called "upload'.

Comment: @user2060451 How is your structure looks like? Where is the delete.php file and where is the upload folder located?

My answer should be valid if upload folder and the delete.php are in the same directory. Edit: You don't miss the slash before upload, right? I've updated my reply so try it again.

Comment: What's returned by `realpath('upload/' . $file);` before the line `if (!unlink ("upload/$file"))`?

Comment: @Imaqtpie I edited the question adding a tree of folder. If not clear, a picture will be. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: a@GeorgeBrighton Not sure if I understood. Those are routes I tried not at the same time. error for ALL attempts: No such file or directory in /home2/braaasil/public_html/openhouse/delete.php on line 27"

Comment: If delete.php is in openhouse folder and upload folder is in public_html folder, try this: `__DIR__ . '/../upload/' . $file`

Comment: @Imaqtpie I added the slash. Same error message:[25-Sep-2013  PHP Warning: unlink(__DIR__/upload/) [<a href='function.unlink'>function.unlink</a>]: No such file or directory in /home2/braaasil/public_html/openhouse/delete.php on line 27

Comment: @user2060451 Try the solution I posted above this comment. It should work with your directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry !
For some reason, DB started to accept both image.jpg and image.JPG even though I had the command strtolower for all entries.

Images are being deleted by the very code is posted in this question. I really appreciate your time and apologize one more time.

For all others: make sure that DB, file and search all all set to lower case since DB may be upper and lower case sensitive.